# Is there a way to assert if an object has been properly constructed before a method is called on it?

Tags: c++, constructor

I ran into this bizarre pointer-less situation in my code and am now wondering if there is a way to detect it (other than crashing).  The code manages to get into an un-constructed object's method.  When b1 is constructed, a has not been constructed, and b tries to use it.  By the time b2 is constructed, a is properly constructed and the code works as expected.

Beyond the obvious, "don't do this in your code," I'm wondering if there's a way to detect this at compile or run time.  The compiler didn't detect it at all, and I just got some obscure and very unhelpful message about running managed code while initializing a DLL when the program crashed.

I tried to test "this", but it's not NULL because memory has been asigned -- it's just that the constructor has not been called so the memory is in an indeterminate state.

I would have thought the compiler would stick in some debug code to detect when this happens, but I guess not.

Is there any assertion or test or compile time switch I can use to detect this situation, or does it just come down to, "if it hurts, don't do that?"

```
 OUTPUT:
 (NULL)
 test

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cstring"

class Apple 
{
    char *sometimesinitialized;

    public:
    Apple () { 
        sometimesinitialized = new char[15];
        strcpy_s(sometimesinitialized, 5, "test");
    };
    void test()
    {
        printf("%s\n", sometimesinitialized);
    }
};

class Ball
{
    public:
    Ball();
};

Ball b1; // OOPS!
Apple a;
Ball b2; // Works as expected

Ball::Ball()
{
    a.test();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    scanf_s("%i");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen? Do you wish the program stops when the call for B is made with "a" as a null pointer or continue?

Comment: Well the code shouldn't have been written this way to begin with, but it wasn't obvious that this situation existed.  The question isn't how do I detect this at run time in a released app, it's, how do I detect that I've been a bad boy so I can fix my code?  A plain old assertion would be enough if I could think of one that would work.  In this case, I built this little test to show the problem, and it very gracefully lets you know there's a null pointer.  In my case I had no idea this was going on and it just crashed like a mac truck.  StackedCrooked's method below is a great solution.

Comment: Also, naming 2 variables 'a', one a global variable of type A, one a member variable of A with type `char &`, unnecessarily complicates the code. Even (especially?) for asking questions about unexpected behavior, it's best to have separate names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an instance of `B` needs to access an instance of `A` then it should be passed to `B`'s constructor.

```
struct B {
    B(A &a) {
        a.test();
    }
};


A a;
B b(a);
```

Comment: Ah, you are a rockstar.  This should be required for constructors to access other same-scope objects IMHO.

Comment: Wow, I wish I could give both of you green checks, because they're both great answers, but I think the other answer is better because it explains why you shouldn't try to get around the problem this way, but rather avoid it altogether.

Comment: Actually, I moved the check here, with the caveat that anyone who reads this really should read the other response by 6502.  You should limit access to objects you have asked for a reference to.

Answer (score 2):

A common pattern to guarantee that an object with static storage is properly initialized, ina fully standard-guaranteed fashion, is as follows:

**global.hpp:**

```
struct Foo;
Foo & globalFoo();
```

**global.cpp:**

```
#include <foo.hpp>

Foo & globalFoo()
{
    static Foo impl;
    return impl;
}
```

Anyone who needs to access the global `Foo` object simply calls `globalFoo()` to obtain a reference. The object is initialized before its first use, and destroyed at the end of the program after everyone who used it has been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Startup and shutdown of a C++ program are two areas in which there is quite a bit of fuzzyness and you should in general try to do the very minimum you need.

The standard says that all static duration variables in a compilation unit will have been initialized when you execute any function in the module, however you are on your own about what is the state of a static duration object DURING the initialization or destruction of static duration objects or what happens about cyclic dependencies.

Moreover you cannot rely on having a static duration object doing for example a "service registration" for the module because the standard says that initialization of static duration variables in a compilation unit doesn't need to be executed before `main` but could be delayed until you access a function in the module; therefore if the access to the module depends on having the module registered the initialization could be simply skipped leaving the module unregistered and not accessible. This late initialization wording was added just to be able to support dynamic libraries in the language, still the fact remains that the standard doesn't mandate such a technique is guaranteed to work.

Another important point is also about implementation problems. For example in windows I've experienced that errors during shutdowns could be simply ignored (so the application **apparently** is closing without problems but in reality it's dying for an access violation during shutdown) and also debugging facilities were not working correctly before the start and after the completion of `main`, making debugging problems in these two areas quite hard.

Consider for example using a logging facility: you are in trouble if you want to call logging during static duration variables destruction and the logging itself depends on static duration variables (may be when you call logging the logging objects have been already destroyed).

Also the sequence in which construction and destruction happens is not guaranteed (except that phrase that says that before calling a function in a compilation unit al static duration variables of that unit will have been initialized). I've experienced that just rebuilding a project without changing **anything** could produce a different sequence, probably because of smart incremental linking techniques).

My suggestion is just to do the minimum you need during static initialization and destruction, and avoid doing anything that can possibly fail. Once you are inside main then explicitly do the initializations you need in the order you want. In a similar way if you keep an explicit control about what happens and in which sequence at shutdown then you'll save many debugging hours.

In the past I was a supporter of lazy and automatic initialization techniques, but IMO C++ is not a language in which this approach is practical because there are not enough guarantees.